# Routes by DNS names in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony

I am asking if it's possible, from Symfony2, using some configuration on routes or something else a redirect based on DNS. Let me explain a bit. I have a project with a admin area (backend on top of SonataAdmin) and a customer area. I would like to point `http://backend.domain.com` to go directly to SonataAdmin login interface and `http://domain.com` points to customer area. Is that possible from within Symfony? Can any give me some example of configuration or a brief explanation around this?

**Update**

This is how the redirection should works:

```
http://backend.domain.com => redirect to http://backend.domain.com/login
http://domain.com => keeps on http://domain.com
```

Is the same as said `backend` goes to admin area.

Comment: Isn't it easier to to do via apache2 ?

Comment: @COil yes, could be but how, two Virtual Host pointing to the same Directory? Aliases? Could you give me a better idea and/or perhaps an example of how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this tiny vhost for your backend:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName backend.domain.com
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /login
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thx, take a look at the edit I have made, is that what your snippet does?